# Let $G$ be finite, $g\in G$, and the conjugacy class of $g$ have $d$ elements. Show $d|g|$ divides $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group, $g\in G$, and the conjugacy class of $g$ has $d$ elements, then show $d|g|$ divides $|G|$

I know why $|g|$ and $d$ divide $|G|$ individually but I can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Hint: The number of conjugates of $g$ is the *index* of its normalizer, and the normalizer contains $\langle g\rangle$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry but I can't figure out where to apply this. I understand what the hint is saying but all I'm getting out of it is that the order of g should divide d. Should I be considering the left action of the normalizer on G?

Comment: $|G|=[G:N_G(\langle g\rangle)]|N_G(\langle g\rangle)|$, and $|\langle g\rangle|$ divides $|N_G(\langle g\rangle)|$.